# Имитация Multipart post запроса использующего CORS при помощи Rest.Sharp

Tags: c#, post, rest, cors, restsharp

Собственно, что я пытаюсь сделать:

- залогинится с помощью кук на `contributor-accounts.shutterstock.com` (сделано!)
- сделать пост-запрос отправляющий туда картинку (проблема!)

Сам код враппера вокруг RestSharp:

```
public class Requester
{
    public RestClient Client = new RestClient();

    public Requester()
    {
        Client.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0";
    }

    private IRestResponse GetSingle(string url, int timeOutMs)
    {
        Client.BaseUrl = new Uri(url);
        var request = new RestRequest();

        request.Timeout = timeOutMs;

        return Client.Execute(request);
    }

    public IRestResponse Post(string url, string filePath)
    {
        Client.BaseUrl = new Uri(url);

        var request = new RestRequest(url, Method.POST);
        request.AddFile("someFileName", filePath);

        return Client.Execute(request);
    }

    public IRestResponse CorpsPost(string baseUrl, string remoteDomainUrl, string filePath)
    {
        Client.BaseUrl = new Uri(baseUrl);

        var basePage = GetSingle(baseUrl, 6000);

        var optionsRequest = new RestRequest(baseUrl, Method.OPTIONS);
        Client.Execute(optionsRequest);

        //some addtitional code here?

        var request = new RestRequest(remoteDomainUrl, Method.POST);
        request.AddFile("someFileName", filePath);

        return Client.Execute(request);
    }
}
```

Вся проблема в том, что отсылка файла (пост) идет на другой домен:

`https://media-upload.shutterstock.com`

и, как следствие, браузер автоматически использует [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#Preflighted_requests). Доп.информацию можно почитать здесь: [тыц](http://grishaev.me/cors)

Итак, вопроса 2:

1. возможно ли вообще симитировать CORS запрос без браузера?
2. Если возможно, то как это сделать при помощи RestShapp? То есть как исправить CorpsPost() метод что бы он работал в принципе?

Comment: Для чего вам вообще Rest.Sharp ?  не проще стандартными средствами C# сделать ? по сути вам нужна только авторизации, и Post Multipart Content.

Comment: @DigitalCore нет, не проще. Кода в 4 раза больше и он менее интуитивный. Я уже пробовал. А сколько займет в учетом имитации CORS вообще не хочется думать :)